# Is it possible to download files from Docker Volume via Docker Desktop application?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-volume

I have created a docker volume as the following:

```
docker create volume test_volume
```

I run my container as the following:

```
docker run --rm -v test_volume:/data collect_symbols:1.0
```

... where (in the container) I can access the test_volume via `/data`.

And when my container runs, I save a `symbols.csv` file as the following in a python script:

```
df.to_csv("/data/symbols.csv", index=False)
```

My container is not a Web server so it just runs a task and then it ends.

Then I go to my Docker Desktop application, and go to the **Volumes** section. I select the **test_volume** Docker volume, and I see the symbols.csv file there, which is good.

On the right hand side of the screen, there are 2 options: `"Save As"` and `"Delete"`. (See below image.)

[image]

Then I click on `Save As` to check the content of the file, it asks me where to save the file, I pick a location in my local computer and click on Save. But the application throws the following error at this point:

[image]

It says `Cannot destructure property 'filePath' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.`

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is it not possible to get the file from a Docker volume in this way? If it is the case, what is the purpose of `Save As` button?

Note: I am running the Docker Desktop Application on Windows.